# Laravel use a controller in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I just start to learning Laravel, I stuck in a part, I want to get data from database and pass it to a blade (view) file then use this view in another view file, and want to pass one variable to a controller but I got this error:

> "Class 'adsController' not found"

**web.php**

```
Route::get('seller/panel', 'sellerController@panel');
```

**panel.blade.php**

```
@include('seller\hook\ads')
```

**sellerController.php**

```
public function panel(){
    $ads = DB::table('ads')->get();
    return view('hook\ads', ['ads' => $ads]);
}
```

**adsController.php**

```
class adsController extends Controller {
  public function getStatus($p) {

    if ($p == 'something') {
      $status = 'yeah';
    } else {
      $status = 'blah blahe';
    }
    return view('hook\ads', $status);
  }
}
```

**ads.blade.php**

```
<div class="ads">
@foreach ($ads as $ad)
{{ $ad->name }}
{{ adsController::getStatus($ad->approved) }}
@endforeach
</div>
```

So, as you see I am tring to get data from database in `sellerController.php` then pass it to ads.blade.php then I want to use `adsController.php` 's function in ads.blade.php, but it can't find `adsController`

Sorry I am newbie to laravel

Comment: It's bad practice to use controllers to output data. Controllers should be used to pass data to views, and showing said view.

Comment: Whats your adsController namespace? just add namespace before controller. {{ Namespace\adsController::getStatus($ad->approved) }}

Comment: what is your advice? @Classified any right way?

Comment: @PayalPandav it is: `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

Comment: Please add and try. @tourTravel

Comment: @PayalPandav still same error

Comment: You could add said function as a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) on your `Ad` model, this would even make the syntax much more readable. `$ad->getStatus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone said, it's not recommended to call the controller from the view.
Here's what I would do :

In your model :

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ad extends Model{
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->approved == 'something' ? 'yeah' : 'blah blaehe';
    }
}
```

In your view :

```
<div class="ads">
    @foreach ($ads as $ad)
        {{ $ad->name }}
        @include('hook.ads', ['status' => $ad->getStatus()])
    @endforeach
</div>
```

In your controller :

```
public function panel(){
    $ads = \App\Ad::all();
    return view('hook\ads', ['ads' => $ads]);
}
```

Comment: This solution looks good, but two problem, first, you not pass any data to getStatus() , should pass $ad->approved to this function. Second, if I want to use this function in another view, what should I do? I did that dirty way because I want to use getStatus() a thousand times in another views.

Comment: I edited my answer. You also need to use `Ad` model in your controller.

Comment: `first, you not pass any data to getStatus() , should pass $ad->approved to this function.` You don't need to pass `$ad`to the method anymore. `getStatus()` is a part of `$ad`

Comment: `Second, if I want to use this function in another view, what should I do?` When you get your Ad from the model, it will automatically have `getStatus()` method available. so you will only need to do the same `$ad->getStatus()`

Comment: You can learn more about Models here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent it's an important part of MVC (Model, View, Controller) like Laravel

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the blade file you could include the following

```
@php
    use App\Http\Controllers\adsController as adsController;
@endphp
```

then on your blade template you could use the controller as you have used here.
But it is a really bad habit to use one directly.

Since you are a newbie to Laravel change that coding practice.

You could use a service provider of a sort if you want that data which needs to be shown on a particular blade view all the time.

Comment: Still return same error, `"Class 'adsController' not found"` on this line `<?php echo e(adsController::getStatus($ad->approved)); ?>`

Comment: i have edited the code a bit, can you look into it now, i had removed the `@php()` into `@php`

Comment: also if that change doesnt solve your issue, then on sellercontroller you could also add the status for all the ads items and send it along with ads variable, that will be another solution

Answer (score 0):

You should try this despite I don't recommend the approach you are trying to achieve.

```
{!! app('App\Http\Controllers\adsController')->getStatus($ad->approved) !!}
```

It should work but that's very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Most often when you get this error when your namespace declaration in the controller is wrong. Typical scenario is where you generate controller stub with Artisan and then move it somewhere else from the default location.

In some cases you need to run:

composer dumpautoload

To generate new optimized class loader map.